# Trying to create git repository and commit files to it but with no luck

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm using TortoiseGIT.

Here is my process:

> 1) Right click on empty folder and click on 'Git create repository
>   here'
>
> 2) Make a bare repository in directory
>
> 3) right click in a different empty folder and click on 'git clone'
>
> 4) clone from URL of created repository
>
> 5) in clone repository create a source file (such as source.cs)
>
> 6) Right click in git clone directory and press 'git commit -> master'
>
> 7) Add source.cs file and commit it
>
> 8) Create a different git clone directory pointing to original repo,
>   attempt to do a git sync

The result is nothing happens, I don't get the source file I comitted in the other repo...

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIT is distributed.  I believe what is happening is you are committing to the local (in the folder created) repository.  You will need to run sync on that repository to push it back to `ORIGIN`.

I had a similar problem when I was switching from SVN to GIT as they are very different in what COMMIT means.  (I am by no means an expert here so I could be way off as well)

Answer (score 2):

Have you created another branch?
If you created another branch and pushed it to the origin repo, you will have to switch to it when you clone, making a local copy of the branch.

This would be in TG:

- right click the clone repo and go to the TortoiseGit menu;
- select "Switch/Checkout";
- choose the `remote/origin/yourBranchNameHere` branch and notice that the "Create a new branch" box is checked and the text box for it is filled with the name of the branch;
- press "OK".

Also, do you remembered of pushing the changes, right?